# Unit Price in Crystal Report is not matching

Tags: c#, sqlite, crystal-reports, desktop-application

I'm working on C# Desktop Application. A crystal report is generated. When I update my unit price. It doens't reflect in my Crystal report.
Database is of SQLite.
Can please someone help me out what the problem is?

Comment: Does it reflect before updating?

Comment: Does it reflect in the DB?

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports Designer, under the ***File*** menu, the developer of the report probably forgot to turn off '***Save Data with Report***'. Either turn it off or ***DiscardSavedData*** in code.

Comment: Hey MilletSoftware,
Thanks for the reponse. 
Basically when I update price value in run time. It works fine until I populate Crystal Report.
Only price accept less than or equal to 999 shows fine but increase in it shows only the first start digit. If I put 1000 it will show only 1 in Crystal Report.
if give 50,000 it will give 50 in Crystal Report.
Please help.